# Calculate the smoothness of a SciPy cubic spline

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate the smoothness of cubic splines generated using [`scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html). The way I want to calculate the smoothness is by taking the integral of the square of the second derivative:

[image: eq]

The SciPy `CubicSpline` accepts the `integrate` and `derivative` methods, but they are not enough for the calculation above. What I can easily do is `.derivative(2).integrate(0,20)**2`, but this is not quite what I need (I am taking the square *after* the integral is being calculated).

Is there an easy way to perform the calculation above? Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SciPy's object model, but can you do the power before the call to integrate (with parentheses to get the order of operations right)? Something like: `(whatever.derivative(2) ** 2).integrate(0, 20)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, what you suggested does not work. And ```.pow()``` does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there: you need to cook up a callable for the second derivative squared:

```
>>> spl = CubicSpline(x, y)
>>> der = spl.derivative(2)
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> quad(lambda x: der(x)**2, 0, 1)     # <--- here
```